# Issue with textbox rounding a number

Tags: c#, winforms, rounding

I have the following code:

```
txtbox1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[11].Text;
```

The value of the selected item of the listview is "33,5" but when the code reachs this line, in the textbox writes 34,00.

I don't know why if there's a text inside a text, I have tried convertingo to decimal before asing to the textbox but still put 34,00. I've tried too puting 33.5 instead of 33,5 but then the code writes in the textbox: 3350,0.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: You want to convert the contents to a string beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
string number = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[11].Text;
```

and check in debug mode what number contains.

I am convinced you have the right value in there, a simple string, but the txtbox1 is applying certain formatting on text change. You should find this out and fix the way content of txtbox1 is formatted after assignment.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks a lot, but in other parts of my code I've made the same and I didn't had any problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: of course, debugging you are sure you can understand what happens, but then you have to fix the code, debugging shows you what is right or wrong but then you must change something to get it fixed. and we cannot tell you eaxctly without seing the code!